# Main activity code disappeared after a force laptop shut down

Tags: java, android, android-studio, main-activity

I was writing an app and I was in main activity (had written thousands of lines of codes). But when I wanted to shut down my laptop, it took a while so I had to push the power button to force a shut down. Then after a while, when I powered on my laptop again and opened Android Studio, all my main activity code was gone! It's so weird.

I can see in project folder that main activity has about 40kb size but it's all empty. So is there something wrong with Android Studio and can I fix it? If not, can I use some tools or tricks to get another version of my main activity file (like changing the last date modified to the one before it or something like that).

Comment: Can you open the Activity file in a plain text editor, like Notepad?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to right click on your MainActivity and choose Local History > Show history

Comment: Thank you so much for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

Check if it is in your android studio history .

Comment: Thank you so much for your help :)